# Equivalent to adapter.notifydatasetchange or Diffutils in Jetpack Compose Lazy Column/Row

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

How to update, delete or add item in a `LazyColumn` in Jetpack Compose ?
Which is easily achieve by `adapter.notifydatasetchange` or `diffutils` in recyclerview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do exactly that on the collection you are passing to `items` function. This is simple as that. If your class is stable (just use `data class`) you are fine, it will just work. Welcome to Compose magic.

If you want the best performance on update/delete/add then expose a stable key in the `items` function, see here for more details: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#item-keys

Example:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MessageList(messages: List<Message>) {
    LazyColumn {
        items(
            items = messages,
            key = { message ->
                // Return a stable + unique key for the item
                message.id
            }
        ) { message ->
            // Display entry here
            MessageRow(message)
        }
    }
}
```

Here, if you provide the key lambda, the compose will know that this entry is the same entry - just with different content. If you do not provide this lambda - index in list will be used as key. So any addition other than at the end of the list would trigger a lot of recompositions. So it is more or less like a diff utils. You only have to provide this, because content equality is handled by compose implicitly - via `equals` of the `Message` object.

So if you want to remove one message from the list - remove it and pass new list to `MessageList`. Compose will handle the rest for you

Comment: What if I change a value in one of the items (say, change a phone number in a list of contacts), how do I tell compose to redraw?

Comment: You have to update the whole list of messages replacing the item you are updating. Compose will use equals to rerender only this changed item

Comment: I am currently trying to achieve the same thing. Is it possible to test this? That only specific items get updated? If I print a Log.d() right before MessageRow(message) it gets shown everytime for each entry even if I add, delete or update specific items.

Comment: @Carlo-Rodriguez i found that both logging and inspecting recompositions with LayoutInspector report recompositions in a strange way, i think this is somehow connected to the way Lazy layouts work. No idea how to test this properly